# Difference between debug & release?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio

Can anyone tell me the difference between debug & release.Used in sharepoint 2010.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/c-sharp-debug-vs-release-performance

Comment: In what context? Compilation, performance, SharePoint scripts etc... If you put no effort into your questions I highly doubt you'll get any meaningful answers in return.

Comment: @NickLarter,compilation context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug:

For developers, easyier to debug code and attach to processes. Also with an added bonus of optimization being off so you can see the varibles values when debugging.

Release:

Its for the clients, optimization is on and hard to see values when debugging thats because there is no need for the compiler to add debugging information.

dll size matters in sharepoint where your constantly adding new dlls to the GAC, Release is smaller and faster to the counterpart debug being slower and bigger

> In general, building and debugging SharePoint solutions is the same as
>   building and debugging other types of projects in Visual Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231592.aspx

c-sharp-debug-vs-release-performance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/c-sharp-debug-vs-release-performance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140439/when-to-use-release-configuration-in-visual-studio-for-sharepoint-solutions

[When to use Release configuration in Visual Studio for SharePoint solutions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60740/when-to-use-release-configuration-in-visual-studio-for-sharepoint-solutions)